# Why we cannot add iVar in Categories?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I would like to first note that actually we "can"

Just use associated objects:

```
@implementation UIButton (BGButtonWithImages)

static char UIB_ImageOfButton;

-(void)setImageObject:(Image *)imageObject
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_ImageOfButton, imageObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

-(Image*)imageObject
{
    return (Image*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_ImageOfButton);
}    
@end
```

But that leads to another issue. Why is it that something that can be done easily with Associated Objects cannot be done regularly? Why does Apple not implement properties in categories like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The synthesized property accessors use instance variables. You're not allowed to add instance variables via categories because there would be no guarantee of uniqueness - the same instance variables might be added by another category.

As you notice, the [inside-out object pattern](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/inside_out_object) lets you define accessors in categories, as long as your key for the associated object table is unique. It's fine to carry on using that. If you want first-party compiler support for generating those accessors you'd have to [ask Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: So if you want property in categories you simply have to implement stuff yourself? Hmm... Apple could have made this automatic.

Comment: If that same instance variables might be added by another category, that can be sorted out at compile time right?

Comment: @SharenEayrs no, it can't. While the capability isn't open to iOS developers, categories can be dynamically loaded at runtime. You don't know, when compiling any one category, what other categories will exist. This already leads to another problem - you can't deterministically replace a class's method in a category because it might also be replaced in another category.

Comment: No. it cannot be sorted out in compile time. Categories are loaded and linked at runtime, when you first call a method of the category. Also, categories can be loaded far in the future (when loading a .xib, or a framework, or a plugin) that suddenly adds a category to an object.